# can we use different yaml file for fine tuning a model with newdataset but has same classes as in previous dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, github, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, yolov8

I have trained a YOLOv8 model with my custom dataset, where I used ultralytics and pytorch. I have the same dataset as the first dataset but the positions of objects in the images are changed in the new dataset. now if I annotate without taking any reference from the first dataset YAML file, will it work?

first trained YAML file be like:

```
train: /home/user/Code/newdata/YOLODataset/images/train/
val: /home/user/Code/newdata/YOLODataset/images/val/
test: /home/user/Code/newdata/YOLODataset/images/test/
nc: 8
names: ["shelf", "tray", "barcode", "box-botte", "mbox", "cobj", "syrup", "half"]
```

fine tuining yaml file:

```
train: /home/user/Code/newdata/YOLODataset/images/train/
val: /home/user/Code/newdata/YOLODataset/images/val/
test: /home/user/Code/newdata/YOLODataset/images/test/
nc: 7
names: ["shelf", "tray", "barcode", "box-botte", "mbox", "syrup", "half"]
```

Will the 2nd YAML file will be suitable for fine-tuning the custom pre-trained model? For the first time I trained with 520 images and 25 epochs. now for how many images and epochs should I fine-tune the model?
thanks in advance

I use Pytorch and Ultralytics. can I follow the above YAML file for fine-tuning?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.